# Formula on a formula field not showing errors but doesn't fire

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have this formula which checks on a picklist field not equal to certain values and if the date is less than today, this formula field should have a value of Overdue or else it should take the value of another field in the same object. As of now this formula doesn't show any errors and it always shows the value of the Status field even when the date is set in the past.
Here is the formula -

```
If (
OR(
TEXT(Status) != "Completed",
TEXT(Event_Status) != "Canceled"
)
&&
(ActivityDate+DurationInMinutes) < TODAY(),
"Overdue",
TEXT(Status)
```

UPDATE -

```
If (
OR(
TEXT(Event_Status__c) != "Completed", 
TEXT(Event_Status__c) != "Canceled"
)
&&
(ActivityDateTime+(DurationInMinutes/1440)) < NOW(),
"Overdue",
TEXT(Event_Status__c)
)
```

Comment: This looks like a formula field and not a validation rule. A validation rule must return a boolean (true/false) value.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the title, it is a formula field, any idea why the above is not working.

Comment: `ActivityDate` is a Date field, not a DateTime field

Comment: @cropredy I made a few changes to the field and put it as an update to the original post. If I check on the datettime now it works, but it doesn't work when I combine it with the values of the Event_Status field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
If (
  AND( /* Event status is neither Completed or Cancelled */
   TEXT(Event_Status__c) != "Completed", 
   TEXT(Event_Status__c) != "Canceled"
  )
   && /* due date is before today */
  (ActivityDateTime+(DurationInMinutes/1440)) < NOW(),
  "Overdue",  /* then overdue */
  TEXT(Event_Status__c)
 )
```

Comment: Thanks Cropredy

Comment: commenting your formulas as you write them often resolves issues :-)

Comment: Sure, Agree to that